# const cast and std launder

Tags: c++, c++17

Modifying a const constructed object after a [const_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast) is UB (I believe due to constant propagation). Is it still UB even when combined with [`std::launder`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder) (which AFAIK prevents some optimizations such as const propagation)?

```
#include <new>
#include <iostream>

struct C
{
    int i;
};

int main(const int argc, const char * const * const argv)
{
    const C c{1};
    auto x = std::launder(const_cast<C*>(&c));
    ++x->i;
    std::cout << x->i << std::endl;
    std::cout << c.i << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Modifying const objects is even given as an example of undefined behavior in standard [intro.execution]/4: "Certain other operations are described in this International Standard as undefined (for example, the effect of attempting to modify a const object)." Why to try to find loopholes in it?

Comment: The purpose of `std::launder` is not to "prevent some optimizations". That's the wrong way to look at it. Its purpose is to communicate a specific thing to a compiler which in turn would allow it to do "the right thing".

Comment: I guess I have put it wrong, perhaps 'to prevent the compiler from making the wrong assumptions' would have been a better way to express it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [const object](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv) - an object whose type is const-qualified, or a non-mutable subobject of a const object. **Such object cannot be modified**: attempt to do so directly is a compile-time error, **and attempt to do so indirectly (e.g., by modifying the const object through a reference or pointer to non-const type) results in undefined behavior**.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. Attempting to modify a const object is UB, period.